# Password recovery program

Tags: c

I'm supposed to use a function and structs to create a program that allows the user to input a list of passwords and a list of password hints and only one of them is the correct one. You're supposed to match your hints with the possible passwords that you have inputted and determine the correct password from there.  Here's a sample run:
Input:
3
password
secret11
qwertyui
Output:
4
*******1
s*******
*e******
*******q
secret11

Here is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Option {
    char password[50];
    int matches;
};
// Checks to see if the given password matches the given pattern.
// Returns false (0) if it does not, or true (1) if it does.
int is_match(char password[], char pattern[]){





}
int main(){
    int N,i;
    printf("Enter the N value\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    struct Option A[100];
    for(i=0; i<N; i++);{
        scanf("%s", &A[i].password);
    }

    int M;
    scanf("%d", &M);

    //struct Option A[100];
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<M; j++);{
        scanf("%s", &A[i].matches);
    }




    return 0;
}
```

My program stops at the first scanf and only lets me input two of the passwords. I don't know how to debug at this step.

Comment: Looking at your program without a rigorous inspection tells me that since you ignore the return value of `scanf()` you can't complain about wrong results.

Comment: how do i not ignore the return value? sorry, im struggling in my programming class right now

Comment: You need to check, specially when the specifier is `"%d"` -> `if (scanf("%d", &target) != 1) problem(); else ok();` But your problem, was the semicolon as @[Ian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29654555/1983495) explained.

Comment: Don't you need a hints field somewhere in  your struct? And what is the matches field for?

Comment: i think the matches field IS the hints field. As in, the starred out words are the words we're supposed to be watching with the original words we inputted

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after your for loop conditions:

```
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
        scanf("%s", &A[i].password);
   }
```

that's a start anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that was a dumb mistake on my part

Answer (score -1):

Just use `fflush(stdin);` before every `scanf()`.

Comment: That's is nothing less than **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**, `fflush()` is only defined for output streams, it might work with the `MSVC` compiler, but it's not specified by the standard, so I and many other would never, never do that.